# How to remove directories if their names are not listed in filenames.txt file?

Tags: bash

I want to delete some sub-directories stored in a folder named `library`. If their names are not present in the `filenames.txt`, then they will be removed.

The content of filenames.txt is

```
ABC
DEF
XYZ
```

Below is my bash script, but it deleted all the sub directories.

```
for file in library/*                                               
do
    grep "$file" filenames.txt &> /dev/null || rm -r "$file"
done
```

Comment: The value of `$file` is `library/something`, not just `something`. So none of them will be in `filenames.txt`. Remove the directory prefix from `$file` when searching for it in the file.

Comment: You should probably use `grep -x` to match the entire line. Otherwise `AB` or `BC` will be considered a match.

Comment: And use `grep -q` to prevent output, rather than redirecting.

Comment: Use `grep -F` so `.`s, etc. in filenames are treated literally.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot for your kind help. Following your suggestion, I have edited my bash script, but it still deletes all the folders. Sorry I am new in bash, I don't know exactly where the problem is. Thanks for your help. `library="library"
for file in "$library"/*
do
  filename="${file#"$library"}"
  grep -xq "$filename" filenames.txt &> /dev/null || rm -r "$file"
done`

Comment: change to `... || echo rm -f "library/$line"` to be sure there are no rude surprises. When you see the the `rm`s are correct, then remove the `echo`. Good luck.

Comment: Can you try this:

```bash 

#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -Fxq "$line" filenames.txt || rm -r "library/$line"
done < <(find library/* -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec basename {} \;)
```

Comment: Update your question to show your edited code. Multiline code in a comment is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t filenames < <(grep -v '^ *#' filenames.txt | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')

for subdir in library/*; do
    name=$(basename "$subdir")
    if [[ " ${filenames[*]} " != *" $name "* ]]; then
        echo "Removing: $name"
        rm -r "$subdir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: IMO this does not really work. If `filename.txt` contains the line `foo.bar`, and you happen to have a file `library/bar`, it will be considered for keeping, because the `grep` succeeds.

Comment: Furthermore, if `filename.txt` contains the line `abcde`, and you happen to have a file `library/ab.de`, this will be considered for keeping, because the dot in the filenam matches the `c` (a dot matches any character).

Comment: @user1934428 you are right, I just realized this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1934428 I updated the code to handle the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: Since your `if` does not really use regex matching and you use `=~` only for substring testing, I suggest that you simplify it to `if [[ " ${filenames[*]} " != *" $dir_name "* ]]`. Another thing to consider is using different variable names: `dir_name` suggests to the reader that the variable contains the name of a directory. However, it could be a directory or a plain file. Similarily `file` may hold the path to a directory or to a plain file, so this name is also a bit misleading.